# How to set Sesame as a stroage backend for Apache Marmotta?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sesame, apache-marmotta

I'm trying to set Sesame as a Storage Backend for Apache Marmotta. I've followed the instructions on this [page](http://marmotta.apache.org/platform/backends.html) but I guess it's missing a few steps because I'm getting a 404 (HTTP Status 404 - /marmotta/storage-native/admin/about.html). Concerning Sesame, I've only deployed the wars.

Any ideas about the missing steps?

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide more details (logs, requests, etc).

Comment: Honestly a gave up on it. I followed the instructions to the letter, no exceptions or anything note worthy on marmotta side just 404s.